# HTML, CSS popup layout

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

[How to set up the css/html code if the A needs to be at the corner of the bottom right- where the red rectangle pointed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUNBl.png)

two things:
*responsive page
*background is overlay. the white rectangle is a popup.

Comment: Can you post the code? What you could do is give the A the following styles. `position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Was coming here to say the same thing as @RBCunhaDesign , that would seem like the way to go to me, as well.

Comment: Yes, just, the A needs to stay at the bottom right corner while shrinking the screen. position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; isn't enough?